# Logging happens when Shift+key is pressed

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keydown

Maybe someone can guide me in the right direction. I am trying to make logging happen if the Shift+key is pressed and not happen if only the Shift is pressed.

At the moment it works as expected, except that when I press Shift it also gets logged :( `Also tried to console.log(event.shiftKey)` but then getting "true" logged

> 

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=> {    
    if(event.shiftKey && event.key) {
      console.log(event.key)
    } 
})
```

Comment: Please explain "if the Shift+key is pressed and not happen if only the Shift+key is pressed"

Comment: Sorry Julian, updated! Nothing should be logged if only the Shift is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check key is not equal to shift

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.shiftKey && event.key !== "Shift") {
    console.log(event.key)
  }
})
```

Comment: Didn't even think about this, thanks a lot!